# Upload base64 encoded images using Facebook sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

It's possible to upload base64 encoded images directly without saving it using Facebook PHP SDK 3.1.1?

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
    'source' => '@/mycoolpic.png', // No need to use FS, base64 encoded image
    'message' => "I'm cool",
));
```

Comment: is that comment in your code something you added or something that was existing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not that I have been aware of, or found out searching. Make sure you use realpath() around the image name, to give the absolute path to the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow in PHP :

```
function base64_to_jpeg( $base64_string, $output_file ) {
  $ifp = fopen( $output_file, "wb" ); 
  fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $base64_string) ); 
  fclose( $ifp ); 
  return( $output_file ); 
}
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$image = base64_to_jpeg( $your_base64_string, 'tmp.jpg' );
$args = array('message' => 'Some message');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath( $image );
$data = $facebook->api('/your_user_id/photos', 'post', $args);
unlink($image);
```

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273198

Comment: @Kev Ok. But this question here is specific to PHP, and the one you linked has no programming language restrictions, that's why I thought I would better answer both of them the same way.. Also why I wouldn't flag any of them as duplicate. Would it be better to answer one of them linking to my answer to the other question ? (I hope this makes sense, sorry for my english)